# Inject Usecases with having more than one parameter using andorid koin dependency injection

Tags: android, viewmodel, clean-architecture, koin, android-koin

i was trying to inject **usecase with having one parameter** using *koin dependency injection*, and got error **Cannot create an instance of class viewmodel**, could you please help me how to inject such usecase in android using koin.

My usecase class

```
class DetailsUseCase(private val repository: Repository) {

    operator fun invoke(id: Int) = repository.getDetails(id)
}
```

my viewModel Class

```
class DetailsViewModel(useCase: DetailsUseCase) : ViewModel() {
    
    fun getDetails(id: Int) = useCase(id)
}
```

my error as follows -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.package.presentation_layer.DetailsViewModel

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.package.presentation_layer.DetailsViewModel.<init> []
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3325)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:3063)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:199)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the view model to your module. For example:

```
val appModule = module {
    viewModel {
        DetailsViewModel(
            useCase = get(),
        )
    }
}
```

and then pass appModule to the modules list when calling startKoin.

Comment: i have done that please check following code 

**private val detailsModule = module {
        viewModelOf(::DetailsViewModel)
    }**

Comment: You shared too little code to figure out what's wrong. Make sure you properly inject the view model `val detailViewModel: DetailViewModel by viewModel()`

Comment: i have used navgraph like `private val viewModel by navGraphViewModels<DetailsViewModel>(R.id.detailsFragment)`

Comment: You need `koinNavGraphViewModel`

Comment: yes right, by misteken i have used **navGraphViewModels** instead of **koinNavGraphViewModel**. Thanks So much @sdex